# react date picker gives unwanted data along with the date value when sent to backend after form submit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, formik, react-datepicker

Hi everyone I implemented react-date-picker in nextjs using formik library. Everything seems fine but when I console log the date or send it to my sever route. I get some unwanted data along with the date. Please, someone, suggest to me how do I get rid of it or How can I properly format the date value in the server route.

Currently, I get date value as shown below

```
2021-05-07T04:00:00.000Z
```

I want to format it as

```
May 7, 2021
```

Comment: Do `const date = new Date('2021-05-07T04:00:00.000Z');` then use `date` object to format value in reactjs

Comment: @SusonWaiba Thank you, so much. You opened up a whole realm of this, date thing that I was unaware of until now. I had no idea about the ISO date format. I figured it out finally. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    const date = new Date(`${req.body.date}`)

    //here req.body.state returns date in ISO format

    const longDate = 
     `${
         months[date.getMonth()]} 
         ${date.getDate()}, 
         ${date.getFullYear()
       }`

    //Output
    May 7, 2021
```